# Extract value from one column based on the value in another in the row below, then find duration until value reached again

Tags: r, lag, dplyr, difftime

I have a dataframe where I need to calculate the duration of a flooding event.

In order to do this, I need the 'From' Datetime:

Datetime of the row above when 'Flooded == TRUE'

and the 'To' Datetime:

Datetime of when the Temp > or = (Temp of the row above when 'Flooded == TRUE')

```
   > head(FloodingDuration)
    # A tibble: 6 x 8
    # Groups:   NestID, Nest, Year [1]
      Beach  Nest  Year Datetime             Temp NestID   TempDrop Flooded
      <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <fct>       <dbl> <lgl>  
    1 LB        1  2014 2014-01-12 09:00:00  27.2 LB1_2014  0       FALSE  
    2 LB        1  2014 2014-01-12 10:00:00  27.2 LB1_2014 -0.0110  FALSE  
    3 LB        1  2014 2014-01-12 11:00:00  27.2 LB1_2014 -0.0190  FALSE  
    4 LB        1  2014 2014-01-12 12:00:00  27.2 LB1_2014 -0.00300 FALSE  
    5 LB        1  2014 2014-01-12 13:00:00  27.2 LB1_2014 -0.0290  FALSE  
    6 LB        1  2014 2014-01-12 14:00:00  27.1 LB1_2014 -0.00400 FALSE
```

I have some of the code, see below, I need the 'From' and 'To' to work.

```
FloodingDuration = group_by (TempData, NestID, Nest, Year) %>%
      filter(minute(Datetime) == 0) %>%
      mutate(TempDrop = Temp - lag(Temp, n=1, default = first(Temp))) %>%
      mutate(Flooded = TempDrop < -0.45) %>%
      group_by(NestID) %>%

      mutate(From = Datetime of Temp at (row above "Flooded == TRUE")) %>%
      mutate(To = Datetime of Temp >= Temp at (row above "Flooded == TRUE"))

      mutate(Duration = as.numeric(difftime(From, To, unit = "days" ))) %>% 
      mutate(MaxDuration = max(Duration) %>% 
      distinct(NestID, MaxDuration)
```

For example:

Row 8083 where Flooded==TRUE

From = Datetime from row 8082

To = row not seen, Datetime where Temp >= 28.920

FYI:

There are 112 different NestIDs, each with around 1200 rows of data.

24 of the NestIDs will have at least 1 Flooded==TRUE, sometimes consecutively, sometimes after the temperature has recovered from the first event.

After each Flooding event, the temperature will gradually rise again.

If it is only possible to find the Duration for the first Flooded==TRUE event for each Flooded NestID, this would still be great.

[image]

Comment: I imagine using some sort of call to `which()` and then subtracting 1 from its return value (to get the value of the row above the condition) should get the rows you want. Providing data for us to use would also help a great deal.

Comment: Hey! Thank you, but is the data I provided not enough? Just substitute a FALSE for a TRUE.

Comment: @bex i gues you can take the `lag` and `lead` to do this i.e

Comment: I might not see the wood because of all the trees ... :). As a general rule, you will find a lot of friends here, if you provide a reproducible example. This helps people get going on your problem. Now let's substitute a FALSE for a TRUE as you suggest, i.e. in line 4. Then you would like to get the `Datetime` from the row above, This you can get with dplyr's `lag()`. But I cannot understand how to get the "To" row identified (also I see you want to check on Temperature changes). I assume you expect a sequence of Flooded == TRUE. How will your algo work out on this. You may identify runs.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have added additional data and an example that I hope clarifies what I mean. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Ray Thank you! I have now added more info that I hope clarifies my problem. Yes there are sometimes a sequence of Flooded==TRUE - see example. I hadn't previously thought about that. I'm not sure how to deal with that. If another event happens after the Temperature has recovered, I figured I was allowing for that by looking for the max duration.

Comment: Please create a small but reproducible example of your data using `dput`. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) link explains that in more detail. Keep only the columns that are required for the question and drop others. Also show us expected output for the data you share. You don't have to share your actual data you can create a fake dataset that is similar to your original dataset but make sure that dataset covers all possible scenarios that are present in your original set so that we don't have a situation where the answer works on the fake dataset but not on real dataset.

Comment: @bex. Below I made a small example to get you started in a step-by-step approach. The `lag()` function helps to check for conditions and pick values that sit in a "given" distance (e.g. 1, 2, ... steps ~ aka rows). This works for extracting the Datetime from the row above. However, if you need to scale, you may not be able to do this in a vectorised form. For this write a function that gets you the output you want and then iterate over all rows. `{dplyr}` offers `rowwise()` (for a start). Hope this gets you started. Feel free to simplify the code if you do not need the "helper" columns.

Answer (score 0):

@Bex .. to get you started, the following might help.
As a rule of thumb, when you have multiple conditions, checks, etc. this may not always be able to perform in a "vectorised" manner, i.e. with a (single) pipe.

I take you step by step through it. You trim the code to make it a bit more elegant.

**(I) reproducible data example and first steps**
To allow others to chip in and help working out an elegant solution ... tadaaa ... a reproducible **data snapshot**. I adapted the `Temp` column to get the conditions you are referring to:

```
df <- data.frame(
    Datetime = seq(from = ymd_hms("2014-04-02 05:00:00"), to = ymd_hms("2014-04-02 15:00:00"), by = "1 hour")
    ,Temp = c(29.083, 29.088, 29.091, 28.920, 27.934, 27.359, 27.491, 27.99, 28.92, 28.93, 28.28)
    ,Flooded = c(rep(FALSE, 4), rep(TRUE, 2), rep(FALSE, 5)))
```

If you are unsure about how your algorithm develops, I recommend to code it step by step introducing interim results in new columns - this is where `dplyr` and friends prevail!

To get the `Datetime` for one of your instances, just use the `lag()` construction you applied earlier in your pipe.
Let's do the same for the Temp, as you want to check on this condition later.
We want to check for when conditions hold. That is a classical "if-then". Using `if_else()` requires type consistency. Thus, I wrap the NA in the respective datatype.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(From = if_else(Flooded == TRUE, lag(Datetime, default = first(Datetime)),as.POSIXct(NA))
        ,Temp_before = if_else(Flooded == TRUE, lag(Temp, default = first(Temp)),as.double(NA)))
```

You now have:

```
              Datetime   Temp Flooded                From Temp_before
1  2014-04-02 05:00:00 29.083   FALSE                <NA>          NA
2  2014-04-02 06:00:00 29.088   FALSE                <NA>          NA
3  2014-04-02 07:00:00 29.091   FALSE                <NA>          NA
4  2014-04-02 08:00:00 28.920   FALSE                <NA>          NA
5  2014-04-02 09:00:00 27.934    TRUE 2014-04-02 08:00:00      28.920
6  2014-04-02 10:00:00 27.359    TRUE 2014-04-02 09:00:00      27.934
7  2014-04-02 11:00:00 27.491   FALSE                <NA>          NA
8  2014-04-02 12:00:00 27.990   FALSE                <NA>          NA
9  2014-04-02 13:00:00 28.920   FALSE                <NA>          NA
10 2014-04-02 14:00:00 28.930   FALSE                <NA>          NA
11 2014-04-02 15:00:00 28.280   FALSE                <NA>          NA
```

**(II) check for the next temp condition**

For each `Flooded == TRUE` we would need to check the remainder of the dataframe.
This is better done in a separate function that you call for each instance of `Flooded == TRUE`.
The idea is to take the dataframe, trim it to the start datetime, and then check when the next time the temp condition is met.

```
check_next_temp_condition <- function(.start_date, .df = df){
    check_df <- .df %>% 
        filter(Datetime >= .start_date) %>%             # trim to start position
        mutate(Temp_cond = Temp >= first(Temp_before))  # check temp condition
}
#-------- let's quickly test what we have
start <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2014-04-02 09:00:00")
(   check_next_temp_condition(start)   )      # brackets around call will print result
```

This gives

```
             Datetime   Temp Flooded                From Temp_before Temp_cond
1 2014-04-02 09:00:00 27.934    TRUE 2014-04-02 08:00:00      28.920     FALSE
2 2014-04-02 10:00:00 27.359    TRUE 2014-04-02 09:00:00      27.934     FALSE
3 2014-04-02 11:00:00 27.491   FALSE                <NA>          NA     FALSE
4 2014-04-02 12:00:00 27.990   FALSE                <NA>          NA     FALSE
5 2014-04-02 13:00:00 28.920   FALSE                <NA>          NA      TRUE
6 2014-04-02 14:00:00 28.930   FALSE                <NA>          NA      TRUE
7 2014-04-02 15:00:00 28.280   FALSE                <NA>          NA     FALSE
```

What follows is standard. We subset for the first time the condition is met and extract the timestamp.

```
check_next_temp_condition <- function(.start_date, .df = df){
    check_df <- .df %>% filter(Datetime >= .start_date) %>%
        mutate(Temp_cond = Temp >= first(Temp_before)) %>%
        filter(Temp_cond == TRUE)   # filter for condition
    #---------- extract Datetime
    if(nrow(check_df) >= 1){ To_date = check_df$Datetime[1]   # check for result
    }else{                   To_date = as.POSIXct(NA)}        # ensure if no result
}

# Test again, if you like
(   check_next_temp_condition(start)   )
```

**(III) running the check function over the dataframe**

The final stretch is to apply the function based on the condition to the rows where the condition is met. ((This is where the vectorised approach for the pipe would break)).
`dplyr` offers you a function `rowwise()` that allows to iterate over each row. You need to remove the rowwise grouping before walking further in a pipe, etc.
Alternatively, you can use other loop approaches.

Below, I just iterate over all rows, e.g. also rows for which the conditions does not apply. To save processing time, you may want to make this conditional again.

```
df <- df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(To = check_next_temp_condition(Datetime)) %>% 
    ungroup()     # undo the rowwise()!
```

You now have a dataframe that allows you to wrap up your other calculations.

```
df
# A tibble: 11 x 6
   Datetime             Temp Flooded From                Temp_before To                 
   <dttm>              <dbl> <lgl>   <dttm>                    <dbl> <dttm>             
 1 2014-04-02 05:00:00  29.1 FALSE   NA                         NA   NA                 
 2 2014-04-02 06:00:00  29.1 FALSE   NA                         NA   NA                 
 3 2014-04-02 07:00:00  29.1 FALSE   NA                         NA   NA                 
 4 2014-04-02 08:00:00  28.9 FALSE   NA                         NA   NA                 
 5 2014-04-02 09:00:00  27.9 TRUE    2014-04-02 08:00:00        28.9 2014-04-02 13:00:00
 6 2014-04-02 10:00:00  27.4 TRUE    2014-04-02 09:00:00        27.9 2014-04-02 12:00:00
 7 2014-04-02 11:00:00  27.5 FALSE   NA                         NA   NA                 
 8 2014-04-02 12:00:00  28.0 FALSE   NA                         NA   NA                 
 9 2014-04-02 13:00:00  28.9 FALSE   NA                         NA   NA                 
10 2014-04-02 14:00:00  28.9 FALSE   NA                         NA   NA                 
11 2014-04-02 15:00:00  28.3 FALSE   NA                         NA   NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ray! I am (obviously!) new to R and learning. This is really helpful, thank you! I will take some time to fully understand what you have done.

Comment: No problem, @bex. we all started small, and I learn every day :). Keep on rocking!
Good to hear that there was something useful for you.

Comment: Hey Ray, quick question: what does the '.' mean for .start_date and .df  ?

Comment: I copied this from some of the {tidyverse}  functions. You will run into problems when you nest functions and use `f(start_date = start_date)` in multiple nests. The points makes it another "name" and the nesting throws no error. For here (single/simple) function, it has not effect ... just a habit now on my end to use the "dot-parameter" name convention in my functions.